# Trying to create custom OData v2 service with data source from S/4HANA Cloud using S/4HANA Cloud SDK

Tags: s4sdk

I am trying to create a custom OData v2 service in java with an S/4HANA Cloud data source using S/4HANA Cloud SDK.  I tried to follow section 8.3 of the SAP Press book "Extending SAP S/HANA: Side-by-Side Extensions with the SAP S/HANA Cloud SDK", except I attempted to substitute OData version 2 for version 4 in the dependency on page 285.  When I execute mvn clean install, it errors out telling me it can't find odatav2 in com.sap.cloud.servicesdk.prov.  (I get a clean install when I use odatav4 instead.)   The reason I want OData v2 is version 4 doesn't appear to be well-supported for SAPUI5 apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setup for OData V2 provisioning looks a bit different. So remove all modifications you did to use OData V4 provisioning. Then add the following:

1. Add the following dependencies (instead of the odata-v4 one) to your `application/pom.xml` file:

   ```xml
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.sap.cloud.servicesdk.prov</groupId>
       <artifactId>odata2.web</artifactId>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
               <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.sap.cloud.servicesdk.prov</groupId>
       <artifactId>odata2.xsa</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.sap.cloud.servicesdk.prov</groupId>
       <artifactId>odatav2-hybrid</artifactId>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
               <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.sap.cloud.servicesdk.prov</groupId>
       <artifactId>odatav2-prov</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Add the following entries to your `application/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml` file, replacing `YOUR.PACKAGE` with a package to search for your OData endpoints:

   ```xml
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>ODataServlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.servlet.ODataServlet</servlet-class>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>org.apache.olingo.odata2.service.factory</param-name>
           <param-value>
               com.sap.cloud.sdk.service.prov.v2.rt.core.CloudSDKODataServiceFactory
           </param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>org.apache.olingo.odata2.path.split</param-name>
           <param-value>1</param-value>
       </init-param>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>ODataServlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/odata/v2/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <context-param>
       <param-name>package</param-name>
       <param-value>YOUR.PACKAGE</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <listener>
       <listener-class>
           com.sap.cloud.sdk.service.prov.v2.rt.core.web.ServletListener
       </listener-class>
   </listener>
   ```
3. Add an OData V2 edmx file to the `application/src/main/resources/edmx` directory.

These steps should get your OData V2 Provisioning service up and running.

Comment: Thanks - now I get an error-free mvn clean install.  I am working on a 'create' (POST).  Assuming the body of the POST gets mapped to a class (for example, MyOrder) - can the class just have sets and gets for each of the entity type's properties in the edmx file?  Then, would I just need the following?
@Create(serviceName = "CFMassSalesOrdersSrv", entity = "MassSalesOrderType")
    public CreateResponse createMassSalesOrders(CreateRequest createRequest)
    {
       MyOrder orderData = createRequest.getDataAs(MyOrder.class);  
       ...
    }

Comment: Yes, that should work. If not, please open a new question.