# Create custom OData v2 service with data source from S/4HANA Cloud using S/4HANA Cloud SDK: web.xml error

Tags: s4sdk

I am still trying to create a custom OData v2 service in java with an S/4HANA Cloud data source using S/4HANA Cloud SDK.  Made web.xml changes as suggested in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55347462/trying-to-create-custom-odata-v2-service-with-data-source-from-s-4hana-cloud-usi) on March 26, but I'm getting an error in web.xml (see below) - it says init-param within servlet is invalid content.

Also, when I attempt to access service metadata through a browser with $metadata, it says 'service not found' and the Cloud Platform 'Default Trace' log has the following:

```
com.sap.cloud.sdk.service.prov.v2.rt.cdx.CDXRuntimeDelegate anonymous 
https-jsse-nio-8041-exec-7 na masssalesorders2application web ha******* 
na#na#na#na#No Runtime Providers present for the URL and 
languageCFMassSalesOrdersSrv
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0" metadata-complete="false">

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    </login-config>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>Everyone</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>All SAP Cloud Platform users</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>Everyone</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>

        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
            <!-- Use CONFIDENTIAL as transport guarantee to ensure SSL connection (HTTPS) on public deployments
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee> -->
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>RestCsrfPreventionFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RestCsrfPreventionFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>RestCsrfPreventionFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>HttpSecurityHeadersFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.servlet.HttpSecurityHeadersFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>HttpSecurityHeadersFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>HttpCachingHeaderFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.servlet.HttpCachingHeaderFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>HttpCachingHeaderFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ODataServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.servlet.ODataServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.apache.olingo.odata2.service.factory</param-name>
            <param-value>
                com.sap.cloud.sdk.service.prov.v2.rt.core.CloudSDKODataServiceFactory
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.apache.olingo.odata2.path.split</param-name>
            <param-value>1</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ODataServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/odata/v2/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>package</param-name>
        <param-value>com.********.s4sdk</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
        com.sap.cloud.sdk.service.prov.v2.rt.core.web.ServletListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

Thanks - the error in web.xml that IntelliJ showed disappeared when I put load-on-startup behind the init-param entries.

When I use this URL within Chrome:  https://masssalesorders2appli********.us3.hana.ondemand.com/masssalesorders2-application/odata/v2/CFMassSalesOrdersSrv/$metadata, the browser returns "Service not available".

The Cloud Platform 'Default Trace' log has 3 rows - each message for each row follows:

```
2019 04 02 14:01:46#+00#ERROR#com.sap.cloud.sdk.service.prov.v2.rt.cdx.CDXRuntimeDelegate##anonymous#https-jsse-nio-8041-exec-6#na#********#masssalesorders2application#web#********#na#na#na#na#No Runtime Providers present for the URL and languageCFMassSalesOrdersSrv 

2019 04 02 14:01:46#+00#ERROR#com.sap.cloud.sdk.service.prov.v2.rt.cdx.CDXRuntimeDelegate##anonymous#https-jsse-nio-8041-exec-6#na#********#masssalesorders2application#web#********#na#na#na#na#No Runtime Providers present for the URL and languageCFMassSalesOrdersSrv

2019 04 02 14:01:46#+00#ERROR#com.sap.cloud.sdk.service.prov.v2.rt.core.CloudSDKODataErrorCallback##anonymous#https-jsse-nio-8041-exec-6#na#********#masssalesorders2application#web#********#na#na#na#na#Request URL: /masssalesorders2-application/odata/v2/CFMassSalesOrdersSrv/$metadata
StatusCode:500 org.apache.olingo.odata2.api.exception.ODataInternalServerErrorException: Service unavailable.
at org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.servlet.ODataServlet.createServiceUnavailableResponse(ODataServlet.java:373)
at org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.servlet.ODataServlet.handleRequest(ODataServlet.java:210)
at org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.servlet.ODataServlet.handle(ODataServlet.java:115)
at org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.servlet.ODataServlet.service(ODataServlet.java:85)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomee.webservices.CXFJAXRSFilter.doFilter(CXFJAXRSFilter.java:83)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.EEFilter.doFilter(EEFilter.java:65)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at com.sap.core.communication.server.CertValidatorFilter.doFilter(CertValidatorFilter.java:157)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.servlet.RequestContextServletFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(RequestContextServletFilter.java:197)
at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.servlet.RequestContextCallable.call(RequestContextCallable.java:131)
at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.servlet.RequestContextServletFilter.doFilter(RequestContextServletFilter.java:209)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.servlet.HttpCachingHeaderFilter.doFilter(HttpCachingHeaderFilter.java:82)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.servlet.HttpSecurityHeadersFilter.doFilter(HttpSecurityHeadersFilter.java:42)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.RestCsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(RestCsrfPreventionFilter.java:113)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
at com.sap.core.connectivity.jco.session.ext.RequestTracker.invoke(RequestTracker.java:55)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
at com.sap.cloud.runtime.impl.bridge.security.AbstractAuthenticator.invoke(AbstractAuthenticator.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
at com.sap.core.tenant.valve.TenantValidationValve.invokeNextValve(TenantValidationValve.java:182)
at com.sap.core.tenant.valve.TenantValidationValve.invoke(TenantValidationValve.java:97)
at com.sap.js.statistics.tomcat.valve.RequestTracingValve.callNextValve(RequestTracingValve.java:113)
at com.sap.js.statistics.tomcat.valve.RequestTracingValve.invoke(RequestTracingValve.java:59)
at com.sap.core.js.monitoring.tomcat.valve.RequestTracingValve.invoke(RequestTracingValve.java:27)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836)
```

When I use the same URL in Postman with 'GET', no rows appear in the 'Default Trace', but a row does appear in 'HTTP Access Log' - it returns '200', but the metadata is not returned.  Since this is my first project for creating an OData v2 service that accesses an S/4HANA Cloud API on the back-end, I'm not sure if I have this set up right:

Here is the start of the java code:

```java
@WebServlet("/salesordercreate")
public class MassSalesOrdersServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    private static final Logger logger = CloudLoggerFactory.getLogger(MassSalesOrdersServlet.class);

    @Create(serviceName = "CFMassSalesOrdersSrv", entity = "MassSalesOrderType")
    public CreateResponse createMassSalesOrders(CreateRequest createRequest)
    {
        MassSalesOrdersEntityType massSalesOrderData = createRequest.getDataAs(MassSalesOrdersEntityType.class);
       .
       .
       .
        try {
            SalesOrder salesOrderPosted = new SalesOrderCreateFluentHelper("", salesOrder).execute(new ErpConfigContext("S4_Sandbox_Sales_Orders"));
            logger.error(salesOrderPosted.getSalesOrder());

            MassSalesOrdersEntityType massSalesOrderCreated = new MassSalesOrdersEntityType();

            massSalesOrderCreated.setSalesOrderNbrStart(salesOrderPosted.getSalesOrder());
     .
     .
     .
                return CreateResponse.setSuccess()
                    .setData(massSalesOrderCreated).response();

        }
```

Comment: Do you get the "error in web.xml" you mention in your editor, or do you also see mentions of this in the log at the startup of your application? Please take a look into the log of your application at startup and add it to your question. Most likely, there is an error thrown there which leads to the OData service not being available.

Comment: The warning for web.xml in your editor may vanish if you reorder the child items of the servlet, putting load-on-startup behind the init-param entries. Can you try that and see if it fixes your error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to implement your own custom handler for a service defined with the [SAP Cloud Application Programming Model](https://help.sap.com/viewer/65de2977205c403bbc107264b8eccf4b/Cloud/en-US/00823f91779d4d42aa29a498e0535cdf.html).

Such a custom handler has to be defined in a plain Java class, not a servlet. The programming model brings its own servlet that handles all requests to the OData service (as you have defined in your web.xml).

Please remove the servlet-specific parts of your class definition (WebServlet annotation + super class).

Assuming that everything else like service definition in CDS is set up correctly, the following implementation of the custom handler should work:

```java
public class MassSalesOrdersServlet
{
    @Create(serviceName = "CFMassSalesOrdersSrv", entity = "MassSalesOrderType")
    public CreateResponse createMassSalesOrders(CreateRequest createRequest)
    {
        // your implementation goes here
    }
}
```

The [help pages](https://help.sap.com/viewer/65de2977205c403bbc107264b8eccf4b/Cloud/en-US/68af515a26d944c38d81fd92ad33681e.html) give more details on custom logic in the SAP Cloud Application Programming Model

Regarding your implementation using the OData virtual data model of the SAP S/4HANA Cloud SDK: please use the service to make the create request, instead of instantiating the fluent helper directly:

```java
new DefaultSalesOrderService().createSalesOrder(salesOrder).execute(...)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guidance.  Another thing I should have mentioned is we would really like to get this working in Neo.  I'd seen in a couple links that OData service creation using the SAP Cloud Platform SDK hasn't been supported in Neo, but maybe by now this has changed.

Comment: According to my knowledge, the SAP Cloud Application Programming Model does not support the Neo environment on SAP Cloud Platform, but Cloud Foundry.